# Find and replace a word in one Excel file accross multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

How do I find and replace a word in one Excel file across multiple worksheets in the same file?

Comment: Be aware that 'find' will NOT find on any sheets that are hidden, so you must first un-hide any hidden sheets that you want to be searched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "Find and Replace" dialog box click the "Options >>>" button and change the "Within" drop down from "Sheet" to "Workbook".